# How can I mute a slack channel/group using slack API?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm trying to mute notifications particular group in Slack workspace. Is there any API method available to do?

I've tried using the web-API method mentioned in this GitHub page https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/users.prefs.set.md. 
It causes no error in response but the channels I provided in the 'muted_channels' parameter wasn't muted.

Comment: Hi there. What exactly do you mean by "mute"? do you want to change notifications? Which undocumented method did you try and what result did you get (errors)? Please add the relevant part of your current code to the question.

Comment: Hi @ErikKalkoken thanks for your response. I've tried the users.prefs.set.md method in postman and got the response as shown in the GitHub link that provided. But the channel ID passed in the 'muted_channels' arg not muted in Slack.

Comment: Truth is that method only works for some of the user prefs. Muted channels might work, but I have never tried it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't have to send a `prefs` payload as ErikKalkoken described, but instead this one. Found it out thanks to this Tweet: https://twitter.com/slackhq/status/457711460425027584

```
{
    "name": "plain_text_mode",
    "value": True
}
```